# Exporting full Landsat image to GeoTIFF in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to get a complete Landsat image in Google Earth Engine, but the export shows some mistakes like this:
[image]

I have calculated the total pixel numbers and it is impossible to have such a huge amount of pixels: 7621X7761X4=236586324

[image]

The link of code is here:https://code.earthengine.google.com/38c19f74ee68ff44a0c2c22c0231cb87

I am wondering is there any wrong with this export code? And is there any way to output GeoTIFF image in patches like we export images in tfrecord?

**Update:**

Although I tried to set the maxPiexels to successfully export a Landsat image according to the suggestion from Sean, it still has some problems:
First, the exported data are automatically separated into some files and I do not know how:
[image]

Second, when I downloaded all these images and open them in ENVI, the total size of these patches is not correct, and all values are 0.

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, you can download full landsat scenes directly from Google Cloud Storage as GeoTiffs https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/public-datasets/landsat

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It really helps a lot. May I ask is there any MODIS cloud storage like this Landsat dataset you mentioned here?

Comment: Not at the moment. Here's the full list https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/browse?filter=solution-type:dataset

Comment: Sorry to ask again. I found the DN values of Landsat-8 data downloaded from google cloud storage are different from values which are exported from Google Earth Engine, although they have exactly same name. The former may 10 times bigger than the later, is there any preprocess for Landsat-8 data in Google Earth Engine?

Comment: The cloud data says they are L1 processed. The Earth Engine catalog contains various products, including TOA and SR processed data.

Comment: I only use SR processed data in Google Earth Engine. The IDs show in Google Earth Engine are the same as those in Google Cloud Storage, so I thought they are the same files, but according to actual DN values, it seems they are not.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you get such a large number of pixels.  I tested your script at found a little over 600 mio pixels.  If you set `maxPixels` parameter of the export to a number large enough to allow the export it should work.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: study_l1.first().select('B4','B5','B2','B3'),
  description: 'test_landsat',
  scale: 30,
  folder: 'landsat8_sample',
  maxPixels: 6.2e
});
```

Alternatively export each band individually to further reduce the maxPixels.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it seems the export image still exists some problems as I showed in the update of this question.