# Problem with pixel values of monthly composites of Landsat 8 when downloading from GEE to Google Drive

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, download, pixel

I am trying to download **Landsat 8** monthly bands using **Google Earth Engine**. While on GEE the pixel values are correct. When I download the images on my PC I'm getting a range from *-1,7e+308* to *+1,7e+308*  and that's the range in each band. Because my study area is large (India), Earth Engine separates each band in several tiles when downloading to Google Drive and again, each tile has the range values I mentioned above. Why that happens?

Here is the code I used:

```
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
//Create mask function
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 2, 3 and 5 are water, cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  var waterBitMask = (1 << 2);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0))
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(waterBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}
//Create Image Collection for Landsat 8 BOA, filtering data from April 2013 to December 2013
//filtering the tiles which intersect India, selecting the predefined bands (VIS, NIR and SWIR)
//Display results
var landsat = landsat.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,6,'month'))
                      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2013,2013,'year'))
                      .filterBounds(table)
.map(maskL8sr);
var landsat = landsat.select('B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B10')
print (landsat)

//Calculate the median for each band (B2 to B7), multiply by scale factor
//(0.0001), and clip to country polygon
var median1 = landsat.select('B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7').reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).multiply(0.0001).clip(table);

//Calculate the median for B10, multiply by scale factor
//(0.1), and clip to country polygon
var median2 = landsat.select('B10').reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).multiply(0.1).clip(table);
Map.addLayer(median1)
Map.addLayer(median2)

//Create variable for each band
var B2 = median1.select('B2_median')
var B3 = median1.select('B3_median')
var B4 = median1.select('B4_median')
var B5 = median1.select('B5_median')
var B6 = median1.select('B6_median')
var B7 = median1.select('B7_median')
var B10 = median2.select('B10_median')

//Export files
Export.image.toDrive({
image: B2,
description: 'B2',
scale: 30,
maxPixels:100000000000,
region: table
});`
```

Comment: If you consult the pixel values of the raster in the GIS you get correct values? By the way, the names of the selected bands should be inside a list like:`landsat.select(['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7'])`.

Comment: [link] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333060/exporting-full-landsat-image-to-geotiff-in-google-earth-engine) I just found that there is a problem in exporting large files as tiff in Earth Engine. I will try the Google Cloud Storage as suggested from @spatialthoughts

Comment: Hope it works. Another possibility might be to convert the image to integer before exporting it. That will reduce the size of the exported image. For example: `B2 = B2.multiply(10000).round().toInt16();`

Comment: I've changed the data type to Int16 but still nothing. I tried the solution mentioned here [link] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313745/problem-with-sentinel-2-ndvi-export-to-tiff-in-google-earth-engine?fbclid=IwAR3Rd5Q4ieNvECebonV-_u_EajPo-JVpbLtJPfnrKg1faK-ny5qObTzEcYg), same results. I will try to download a smaller region and I post the results here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `region: table` in the export part I managed to export the image and the pixel values are correct

```
//Export files
Export.image.toDrive({
image: B2,
description: 'B2',
scale: 30,
maxPixels:100000000000,
region: table
});`
```